# No definition or extension method - ISupportInitialize

Tags: c#, .net, .net-reflector

I'm decompiling a dll into C#. One of the decompiler generated project contains 1000+ buggy lines which one like below:

```
this.pictureBox1.BeginInit();
```

> Error 385 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' does not contain a
>   definition for 'BeginInit' and no extension method 'BeginInit'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

There is no BeginInit() method for regular Picturebox. I simply commented out the lines:

```
//this.pictureBox1.BeginInit();
```

Then I've examined another decompiler's output, it looks like below and VS compiler hasn't previous error:

```
((ISupportInitialize)this.pictureBox1).BeginInit();
```

Because of a crash, I couldn't export all sources at once with the second decompiler. Now I'm not sure what I have to do. I couldn't run & debug the project because of other errors need to be cleared first. My options are:

1. Just comment out the lines.
2. Modify and insert (ISupportInitialize) tag.
3. Create an extension method if possible.

Last option seems easiest to me. Can I create BeginInit() extension method, will it work without any problem? And how can I implement & use ISupportInitialize?

Comment: I think solution 2 is the "right" one. At least that's what the designer does. Create a form with some controls and you'll see a lot of lines like `((ISupportInitialize)this.pictureBox1).BeginInit();` in the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static class PictureBoxExtension {
   public static void BeginInit(this PictureBox pb){
     ((ISupportInitialize)pb).BeginInit();
   }
}
```

Or even better, you can try this for all controls supporting `ISupportInitialize`. This is hidden from normal access because it's implemented ***explicitly***, so we can use this extension to expose it (without casting):

```
public static class SupportInitExtension {
   public static void BeginInit<T>(this T c) where T : ISupportInitialize {
     c.BeginInit();
   }
}
```

Comment: Error: Extension method must be defined in a top level static class; PictureBoxExtension is a nested class.

Comment: @NimeCloud yes, you should try searching on `extension method`. That's because you don't know how to use it. It should be placed in the outermost namespace.

Comment: Ok got, it. It was the second level static class, now it's ok. When I confirm, I'll mark as answer.

Comment: SupportInitExtension would be better bec. of there are many different controls use BeginInit & EndInit.

Comment: @NimeCloud I also updated it with the better code, you can call the `BeginInit` directly on any control implementing `ISupportInitialize`. You can also do the same for `EndInit`.

Comment: @NimeCloud consider accepting the answer, it would be a good encouragement for any answerer :|

Comment: For .NET 2.0 extension methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522605/using-extension-methods-in-net-2-0