# How to enable C# 9.0-preview

Tags: c#, .net-5, c#-9.0

I have downloaded and installed `v5.0.0-preview.5`. My project is targeting `net5.0` but `C# 9.0` is not working. How can I enable `C# 9.0`?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2019, Visual Studio Code, or just using the command-line and/or MSBuild?

Comment: Visual Studio 16.6.2. My project target net5.0 and build is successful but when I use any C# 9.0 feature it does not work and build fails

Comment: Please post the exact compiler output error message from the Output window (not the Error List window), including the line that shows `csc` being invoked by MSBuild.

Comment: And as I asked earlier, please post the results of what happens when you try to build your project by calling `csc.exe` directly from the command-line without using VS or MSBuild.

Comment: I think that the version for c# 9 in dotnet 5 preview 5 is the same as in dotnet 5 preview 4.  Using the instructions below one can compile the sample code from the preview 4 release notes, but you don't get the exciting "hot" bits from Mads presentation from May 20.  eg. data class doesn't work nor does the "init" keyword for read-only properties.

Comment: You can track features, which are implemented already in [feature status](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md) page. Records are still in progress

Comment: @JerzyGrzelec the VS version you use is too old. Even with the latest Preview for both VS and .NET Core though, only a couple of C# 9 features are available. A better question would be `How can I use C# 9's feature X?`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski how can Linqpad use records? Even sharplab.io chokes. Is an extra library or switch needed?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In sharplab you can switch to roslyn branch https://imgur.com/a/xWcCHJd

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski chokes unless you create an empty `IsExternalInit` property. .NET 5 Preview 5 though doesn't even recognise `record`. So how does Linqpad 6 do it?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Preview 6 was released a few hours after the last comment. Records work with a little workaround now

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### As of October 2020:

Please see @Pac0's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64386529/159145

### As of June 2020:

[According to this page in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) you need to edit your `*.csproj` to set the `<LangVersion>` to `preview`.

Also mentioned in the blog-post about the preview-release, but not the above documentation page, [is that you need to update your project's `targetFramework` property too](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-preview-4-and-our-journey-to-one-net/) to `net5.0` <sub>(this is because the C# design team decided to restrict entire C# language versions to minimum BCL versions, unlike previously where you could use C# 7 with even .NET Framework 2.0 [provided you reimplemented your own missing BCL types like `ValueTuple` and `ExtensionAttribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522605/using-extension-methods-in-net-2-0)).</sub>

So your `*.csproj` file should look like this:

```
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
   <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: For those who don't know how to open the project file `*.csproj`: Right click your project on  the `Solution Explorer` and choose `Edit Project File`.

Comment: @JerzyGrzelec Try building your project from the command-line by invoking `csc.exe` directly first, and then try with `msbuild`. You may have other properties in your `.csproj` file that are overwriting them or VS may be using a different compiler instance (e.g. if you're using a compiler imported via NuGet instead of the VS2019 compiler).

Comment: @Dai 9.0 is not on my list. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @JerzyGrzelec I removed the `csc langversion` part of my answer because it was inaccurate and misleading.

Comment: @JerzyGrzelec this does work. Most of the C# 9 features aren't released yet though. Have you tried using any of the features that *are* available? Have you tried installing one of the Preview versions of Visual Studio 2019? Records aren't released though, even in the latest preview

Comment: Records work in LINQPad 6 beta, but I think that one downloads the roslyn preview assemblies, and that the Visual Studio preview has more of a release cycle that is lagging slightly behind.

Comment: Not any more - .NET 5 Preview 6 was release yesterday with record, init support

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same issue. I installed .NET 5 Preview 6 (x64) on an up-to-date VS2019 (16.6.3). My langversion is set to `preview` and the compiler even tells me that it is running on a preview version. Tried some features like init and records, but only got syntax errors.

Comment: Ok, I had to use Preview 8 from the development branch and `dotnet build` directly. Using it out of VS2019 did not work for me sadly.

Comment: @PuerNoctis Could you please share the link to Preview 8 ?

Comment: @AnuViswan I have the preview from https://aka.ms/dotnet/net5/dev/Sdk/dotnet-sdk-win-x64.exe. The only thing that still is a little bit awry, is that I have to use `dotnet build` on the .csproj directly from CLI. Building out of VS2019, even with the "Use .NET Core Preview SDK" setting enabled, didn't work.

Comment: @PuerNoctis Thanks, finally managed get it running. Interesting, I was able to do build within VS2019. I am running VS2019 Preview , Version 16.7 Preview 3.1

Answer (score 14):

As per October 2020,

1. you can explicitly use the 9.0 language version in .csproj
2. Using target framework as .net 5 [implicitly uses C# 9 by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults) .

The .csproj should be as such:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You *can* add `<LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>` if you wish, but it should be optional.

OutputType can be adapted, of course, and you'll need the [.NET 5 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0).

See for instance [this blog](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/08/07/getting-setup-with-c-9-preview/) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly Download [.NET 5](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) and then install [Visual Studio Preview Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/). You will now have access to the latest features of C# 9. Also make sure that you project file includes the following.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone sees this, you can use the VisualStudio installer to do this now.