# Enabling C# 9 in .NET 5 Preview 5 raises a compiler error for the new C# 9 feature

Tags: c#, .net-5, c#-9.0

I followed this answer: [How to enable C# 9.0-preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398572/how-to-enable-c-sharp-9-0-preview) to enable C# 9.

I installed .NET 5 preview 5 which includes the new C# 9.

> Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0-preview.5.20278.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

I try to use [C# 9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/):

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
}
```

with a project setting like:

```
<LangVersion>9</LangVersion>
```

but I get a compilation error:

> Error    CS1617    Invalid option '9' for /langversion. Use '/langversion:?' to list supported values.

I didn't find 9 in the list when run:

```
csc -langversion:?
```

The list is:

```
default
1
2
3
4
5
6
7.0
7.1
7.2
7.3
8.0 (default)
latestmajor
preview
latest
```

Then I used as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398572/how-to-enable-c-sharp-9-0-preview), but it can't help and also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version).

```
<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
```

But I get a compilation error.

> Program.cs(26,40): error CS1014: A get or set accessor expected

What did I miss to do to use C# 9 in .NET 5 preview 5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable C# 9.0-preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398572/how-to-enable-c-sharp-9-0-preview)

Comment: No, it didn't help, and no mention for c#9 setting. I listed lang versions as seen by csc.

Comment: Could you try another feature of `C#9` (for example, [Pattern Matching in C# 9.0](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2850) or [Target-typed `new` expression](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/100)) with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62398665/12833205). It seems that most of the features are in progress, and only some of them merged into the `preview` branch. Feature statuses can be tracked [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md).

Comment: @IliarTurdushev, that's what it is, I also tried using random c# 9 features, but they are not all included in this preview, tried the "Target-typed `new` expression" and that worked.

Comment: @Iliar Turdushev, it seems that majority of c#9 are in [progress](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md) and have to wait to preview7 at least.

Comment: @M.Hassan the duplicate is actually correct. If you want to use a preview language version, you set `preview` in the LangVersion tag. In fact, you don't even need to set `preview` - it's the default choice when using preview .NET Core versions. Very few C# 9 features are available in  Preview 5 though.

Comment: @M.Hassan a better question would be how to use specific C# 9 features, assuming they are released

Comment: @M.Hassan the .NET Preview 6 that was released just yesterday allows the use of eg records, init and other features. You don't have to do anything to enable them, just set the language version to `preview`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, good news and valuable, I'll try it and feedback.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,I installed preview6 and set the language to preview. It seems that it's not supported yet, I get error: `error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit' is not defined or imported`. Do I miss something?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I modified the title of the question, and record feature is working.

Answer (score 7):

I enabled C# 9 as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398572/how-to-enable-c-sharp-9-0-preview) and @PanagiotisKanavos:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  <LangVersion>Preview</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

.NET 5 Preview 5 or Preview 6 don't support the `init` feature and majority of C# 9.

I installed latest SDK bits of development from
https://aka.ms/dotnet/net5/dev/Sdk/dotnet-sdk-win-x64.exe.

Currently preview 8 is available (version 5.0.100-preview.8.20327.5).

I can build projects including `init` feature in Visual Studio 2019.6.2 (the editor still show red lines, but build success) or using Visual Studio Code (perfect, and IDE sense the new C# 9 syntax).

Most, almost all, features of C# 9 in [the blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/) are working fine with .NET 5 Preview 8.

**Update July 3, 2020**

**Alternative Solution**

For working with .NET 5 Preview 5, install the package `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset, Version 3.8.0-1.20330.5`. It support `init` feature and many c# 9 new features.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset -Version 3.8.0-1.20330.5 -Source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/roslyn/api/v3/index.json
```

**Update Aug 7, 2020**

Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7 is released with support C# 9.

In developer Command Prompt, type the command:

```
csc -langversion:?

Supported language versions:
default
1
2
3
4
5
6
7.0
7.1
7.2
7.3
8.0 (default)
9.0
latestmajor
preview
latest
```

You see `9.0` in the list above, and you can define `LangVersion` as 9.0:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You need not to install Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset v 3.8.0-1.20330.5 because C# 9 is supported.

Comment: For me it works with preview 8 and invoking `dotnet build` directly from CLI. Building from VS2019 gave me compiler errors. May you have a clue why?

Comment: Version is 16.6.3, and using `init` it gives me the message `error CS1014: A get or set accessor expected`. MSBuild output tells me that the preview version of .NET is used, but maybe it does not recognize the preview SDK for .NET 5? As I said, the same code compiles when running the `dotnet build` on the .csproj file without any alterations or command line switches, it's weird.

Comment: Oh, and I have the 'Use preview featuers of .NET SDK' in the settings of VS checked.

Answer (score 1):

Following *[Getting Setup With C# 9 Preview](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/08/07/getting-setup-with-c-9-preview/)*:

There are two main things specific to Visual Studio.

- Ensure that Visual Studio is updated to the very latest version. I cannot tell you how many times things don't work in Visual Studio, but do work from the command line or Visual Studio Code, and it's because of the version of Visual Studio.
- Secondly, you need to go menu *Tools* → *Options* → "Preview Features" and then tick the box that says "Use previews of the .NET Core SDK". I think they added this feature so that you could "play" with the preview SDK's, but not have your everyday work being built by preview features. But you need it ticked for things to work.

[image]