# How to use C# pattern matching with tuples

Tags: c#, switch-statement, c#-8.0

I'm experimenting with switch statement pattern matching, and I'm looking for a way to return false if either value in a two value tuple is zero. This is the code I'm trying:

```cs
static bool IsAnyValueZero((decimal, decimal) aTuple)
{
    switch(aTuple)
    {
        case (decimal, decimal) t when t.Item1 == 0 || t.Item2 == 0:
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In VSCode 1.47 and dotnetcore 3.14 I get a compile-time error:

> CS8652: The feature 'type pattern' is in Preview`

What is the best compatible way to write this code?

Comment: Do you have any setting overriding the `LangVersion` on your csproj? [Tuple pattherns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#tuple-patterns) are a [C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8) feature.

Comment: @PauloMorgado No

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use c# tuple value types in a switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355630/how-to-use-c-sharp-tuple-value-types-in-a-switch-statement)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Type pattern` in `C# 8` does not support matching against tuple type in the form `(decimal, decimal) t`. But we can match against tuple type by specifying type [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netcore-3.1) that is used to represent tuples in `C#`:

```
public static bool IsAnyValueZero((decimal, decimal) aTuple)
{
    switch (aTuple)
    {
        case ValueTuple<decimal, decimal> t when t.Item1 == 0 || t.Item2 == 0:
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q5jVmx).

---

Another way to write your code is to use [`tuple pattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0#expressing-patterns):

```
public static bool IsAnyValueZero((decimal, decimal) aTuple)
{
    switch (aTuple)
    {
        case (decimal i1, decimal i2) when i1 == 0 || i2 == 0:
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or we can rewrite this code the next way:

```
public static bool IsAnyValueZero((decimal, decimal) aTuple)
{
    switch (aTuple)
    {
        // Discards (underscores) are required in C# 8. In C# 9 we will
        // be able to write this case without discards.
        // See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3.md#type-patterns.
        case (decimal _, decimal _) t when t.Item1 == 0 || t.Item2 == 0:
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also we can specify matching values explicitly:

```
public static bool IsAnyValueZero((decimal, decimal) aTuple)
{
    switch (aTuple)
    {
        case (0, _):
            return true;
        case (_, 0):
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5IDFvH).

---

`C# 9` adds improvements to [`type pattern`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3.md#type-patterns) so that we will be able to match against tuple type using the next syntax (as in your original code sample):

```
switch (aTuple)
{
    // In C# 9 discards (underscores) are not required.
    case (decimal, decimal) t when t.Item1 == 0 || t.Item2 == 0:
        return true;
}
```

This feature is in `C# 9 preview` and it can be [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398572/how-to-enable-c-sharp-9-0-preview).

Comment: Thank you. I'm confused though because I thought I was using a C# 7.0 feature by following this article. Where have a gone wrong?

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/#more-patterns-in-more-places